# PowerShell Single Line Huge Memory Usage

Tags: powershell, memory

I'm trying to use the below command. Whenever I use this, memory usage is extremely high. Is there a way to lower memory usage while completing the same task?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\" -Recurse |
  sort -descending -property length | 
  select -first 20 fullname, @{Name="Gigabytes";Expression={[Math]::round($_.length / 1GB, 2)}}
```

Comment: 1. Remove the parens `()` from around the `"C:"`. 2. is the `-r` supposed to be `-Recurse` or `-ReadOnly` - it's ambiguous, and the command should fail. If it's `-Recurse`, then there's no way to reduce the memory while keeping it a one-liner or without using temporary files; `Sort-Object` can't sort without having everything it needs to sort in memory, and searching _all_ of the files on C: is going to result in a very large number of files, even on a freshly-installed Windows system.

Comment: Thanks for your response, -r is for recurse. The command itself works; it just eats a lot of memory. I wanted to be able to find the largest files on the hard drive, and sort them by largest to smallest while somehow keeping the overheard for memory low.

Comment: If you want to find the largest file(s) on the drive while minimizing RAM usage, you can do it at the expense of time taken and using temporary files. Try working with each directory individually, finding the largest file in the directory, appending its information to a file (I'd use a CSV), then read in the file and sort its entries, taking the 20 largest.

Comment: The problem is that `Sort-Object` needs to receive all output before processing, you could try filtering only the properties of interest (fullname and length) before sorting, this would increase the time in takes but also should reduce memory usage.

Comment: You're missing a curly brace at the end.

Comment: Josh, @JeffZeitlin, I've updated the post for clarity and to avoid incidental distractions, by removing the `(...)` around `"C:\"` and expanding `-r` to `-Recurse`. Jeff,  `-r` is perhaps unexpectedly unambiguously interpreted as `-Recurse`, because it is the only one among the _static_ parameters whose name starts with `r`.

Comment: @js2010, I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

This should be very efficient compared to what you're currently doing, basically it leverages the [`SortedSet<T>` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=net-7.0) and a custom [PowerShell Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2) implementing [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-7.0) and [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-7.0). The logic inside the anonymous function ensures that the sorted set will always have a **maximum of 20 elements**  (change the `$sorted.Count -lt 20` as needed depending on how many files you want as result) so memory usage should be much lower.

```bash
class SimpleFile : System.IComparable, System.IEquatable[object] {
    [string] $FullName
    [Int64] $Length
    [double] $Gigabytes

    SimpleFile([IO.FileInfo] $File) {
        $this.FullName  = $File.FullName
        $this.Length    = $File.Length
        $this.Gigabytes = [Math]::Round($File.Length / 1Gb, 2)
    }

    [int] GetHashCode() {
        return $this.FullName.GetHashCode()
    }

    [int] CompareTo([object] $That) {
        if($diff = $this.Length.CompareTo($That.Length)) {
            return $diff
        }
        return 0
    }

    [bool] Equals([object] $That) {
        return $this.FullName -eq $That.FullName
    }
}

$result = Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse -File -EA 0 | & {
    begin {
        $sorted = [System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet[SimpleFile]]::new()
    }
    process {
        if($sorted.Count -lt 20) {
            $null = $sorted.Add($_)
            return
        }
        if($sorted.Min.Length -lt $_.Length) {
            $null = $sorted.Remove($sorted.Min)
            $null = $sorted.Add($_)
        }
    }
    end {
        $sorted.Reverse()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a mostly cmd solution that runs in half the time (4 min vs 8 min for me), and no great amount of ram to speak of.

```
cmd /c 'dir /s c:\ | findstr /v "Directory of" | findstr /v "<DIR>" | findstr /v "<JUNCTION>" | findstr /v "Total Files Listed:" | sort.exe /+20' | select -last 20


09/13/2018  04:45 PM       362,337,255 78ec5a6bf483ef155dc2a311e526f8a5.cab
09/23/2022  02:24 PM       379,584,512 clonezilla-live-3.0.1-8-amd64.iso
09/13/2018  04:45 PM       445,038,363 8bb1cf01f3ce1952f356d0aff91dbb2f.cab
09/13/2018  04:45 PM       445,038,363 8bb1cf01f3ce1952f356d0aff91dbb2f.cab
04/13/2012  03:02 PM       481,143,404 Data1.cab
02/23/2022  12:10 PM       540,587,242 Miller_MUS171_Lecture02_v2.mp4
05/17/2017  06:27 PM       551,624,704 maple.help
09/13/2018  04:44 PM       600,753,345 a32918368eba6a062aaaaf73e3618131.cab
09/13/2018  04:44 PM       600,753,345 a32918368eba6a062aaaaf73e3618131.cab
11/10/2022  03:12 AM       641,728,512 BaseLayer.vhdx
11/10/2022  03:12 AM       641,728,512 BaseLayer.vhdx
11/09/2022  09:17 AM       687,780,220 Windows10.0-KB5019959-x64.cab
12/12/2017  01:45 PM       740,060,956 2ddf168b.msi
09/13/2018  04:45 PM       760,142,380 9722214af0ab8aa9dffb6cfdafd937b7.cab
09/13/2018  04:45 PM       760,142,380 9722214af0ab8aa9dffb6cfdafd937b7.cab
06/02/2016  03:19 PM       894,730,632 392b35b.msi
04/18/2021  03:03 PM       905,672,704 37b241d4.msi
06/13/2022  12:52 PM       905,672,704 37b241d7.msi
04/18/2021  03:03 PM       905,672,704 Stata17.msi
01/12/2018  03:06 PM     1,075,667,093 windows10.0-kb4056891-x64.msu
```